# Is it OK for two tables to reference each other?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, orm, relational-database

I have two tables, Team and Player (one to many).

My first question, is it bad practice to have both tables reference each other like so?

```
Team: (id (pk), name, captain_id (fk))
Player: (id (pk), name, team_id (fk))
```

I'm using JPA and hibernate with the following setup.

```
@Entity
public class Player {

   @Id
   @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
   private int id;

   private String name;

   @ManyToOne
   @JoinColumn(name="team_id")
   private Team team;
}

@Entity
public class Team {

   @Id
   @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
   private int id;

   private String name;
   private int captainId;


   @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = {CascadeType.ALL})
   private Set<Player> players;
```

At the moment when a new Team is created, the id of the Player who creates it is        passed as a parameter. It works fine but it doesn't feel right doing it manually.

```
public void createNewTeam(Player player, Team team){

    Set<Player> players = new HashSet<Player>();
    Team team = new Team("Cowboys", player.getId(), players);    //player.getId is the captain()

    player.setTeam(team);
    players.add(player);

    PersistenceUtil.merge(team);    
}
```

Is there a way to change the Entities somehow to do this automatically? Or do I need to change the tables?

I have been trying to convert the Objects into JSON using gson but to no avail. I think it has something to do circular referencing. (yes I am a noob in too deep!)

Comment: Of course its ok to have a 1-N BIDIRECTIONAL relation, that's why the relation exists! Set both sides of the relation

Answer (score 0):

What you described here:

```
Team: (id (pk), name, captain_id (fk))
Player: (id (pk), name, team_id (fk))
```

**Is wrong, and shouldn't be configured like that.**

If you want to configure One to Many association between 2 entities,

**then the right way to do it is by:**

First, decide which entity will be the `Many` and which will be `Single (One)`, in our case it's pretty simple. Each player belongs to `One` Team, and Each Team has `Many` players.

Team --> One

Player --> Many

Second, if you'll try to represent that association with Tables, then the Many (Player) should own fk of One (Team), **and Team shouldn't hold fk of Player, There should be only one fk in this association.**

Why?

Let's say that you have a team on Team table with PK of 211, that team has many players let's say players with IDs of 100, 101, 102.

you can't have 3 records (for 3 different players 100, 101, 102) on Team table with the same PK 211

Answer (score 0):

I think there has to be an Admin person who adds both teams and players.
First he can create a team with basic details about the team like name and description.
Then he can add a player with his details, select a team for him and a flag to indicate if he is the captain.

So the table structures would be like this.

```
Team: (id (pk), name, description).
Player: (id (pk), name, team_id (fk), is_captain).
```

But as you said, a player can create the team, then its possible that every player can create a team. So you will have to control this by some role.

So the good approach will be to add the Team first, then the players by some Admin person.

Answer (score -1):

It's possible, but quite limiting. If you add a Team first, then it's captain should be empty, because you didn't create Player yet. Then you have to update your Team, after the Player-Captain has been created. Same problem vise versa.

I would start with moving captain property to a player:

```
Team: (id (pk), name)
Player: (id (pk), name, team_id (fk), is_captain)
```

That way you don't have to do those updates back and forth.

Your function will look something like:

```
public void createNewTeam(Player player, Team team){

Set<Player> players = new HashSet<Player>();
Team team = new Team("Cowboys", players);    

player.isCaptain(true);
player.setTeam(team);
players.add(player);

PersistenceUtil.merge(team);    
}
```

Comment: I should have mentioned that the Player/captain creates the Team, so its impossible for a Team to be created before the Player. Would your answer still be the better way in this case?

Comment: `It's possible, but quite limiting`  --> maybe it's possible but definitely bad practice and wrong to do.